# How can I make my filter function for my table case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I have a search function on my table and it is only searching for the exact keyword. It will not display data which are not properly capitalized. How can I make it case insensitive so I can display those data even I typed all lowercase words? By the way I'm using ESLINT rules. Here is my javascript code:

```
myFunction () {
  var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value
  var targetTable = document.getElementById('myTable')
  var targetTableColCount

  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    var rowData = ''

    if (rowIndex === 0) {
      targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length
      continue // do not execute further code for header row.
    }

    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
      rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent
    }


    if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) === -1) {
      targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none'
    } else {
      targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use all lower case (or all upper case) for the comparison. You really should use semi-colons to terminate statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) string method.

```
if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
  targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none'
} else {
  targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you're doing more work than necessary. If the intention is to show rows that have the search text, then use the *textContent* of the row rather than concatenating all the cell values, and also set the display to "none" or "", so the element adopts its default or inherited display without you having to program it. E.g.

```js
function doSearch() {
  var searchText = document.getElementById('i0').value.toLowerCase();
  var table = document.getElementById('t0');
  var row, rows = table.rows;
  // Skip first row
  for (var i=1, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    row = rows[i];
    row.style.display = row.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) == -1? 'none' : '';    
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="t0">
  <tr><th>Index<th>name
  <tr><td>0<td>Foo
  <tr><td>1<td>Bar
</table>
Search text:<input id="i0">
<button onclick="doSearch()">Do search</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
    if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) === -1) {
      targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none'
    } else {
      targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row'
    }
```

Lets change it to:

```
    if (isInsideInsensitive(rowData,searchText)) {
      targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none'
    } else {
      targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row'
    }
```

With additional function:

```
function isInsideInsensitive(a, b){
     return a.toLowerCase().indexOf(b.toLowerCase()) != -1;
}
```

Take a look at the **isInsideInsensitive** function